# Changing the input I receive from a program from a int to a string beginner

Tags: java, string

I wrote a program that is supposed to simulate grading quizzes, but I want to change the input I receive from a int to a string, so I can type in a, b, c, d, as the answer to a quiz.  How should I do this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Quizzes1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int Questions;
        int answers;
        int Quizzes;
        int numOfQs = 0;
        String phrase= "";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many questions are in the quizz?");
        Questions = scan.nextInt();

        char[] key = new char[numOfQs];

        int[] canswers = new int[Questions];
        for (int i=0; i<canswers.length; i++)
     {
  System.out.println("Please give the correct answers " + (i+1) + ": ");
  canswers[i] = scan.nextInt();
     }

        while (!phrase.equals("n"))
        {

            double Correct = 0;
            double Incorrect = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<canswers.length; i++)
            {
            System.out.println("What are the answers that the students put");
            answers = scan.nextInt();
            if (answers == canswers[i])
                Correct++;
            else
                Incorrect++;
            }

            System.out.println("There are " +Correct + " correct answers and " +Incorrect
                +" incorrect answers");
            double Percent = ((Correct / (Correct + Incorrect)) * 100);
            System.out.println("The percentage correct is " +Percent +"%");
            phrase = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Would you like to grade another quiz y/n");
            phrase = scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as a,b,c and d are singls letters, why don't you read characters instead of int or even string?

Just try

```
scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

using characters, you can still use this part of your code:

```
if (answers == canswers[i])
    Correct++;
else
    Incorrect++;
}
```

That's pretty similar to dasblinkenligh's answer